# How to get the byteArray of an image in gallery, inside the onActivityResult method?

Tags: android, arrays

In an activity i have a button called "Add Image", clicking on the button takes the user to the gallery, from which one image can be selected and this image should be added into the database and showed in the activity using an ImageView.

Here is the onClickListener on the "Add Image" button.

```
addImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,

android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            in.setType("image/*");
            in.putExtra("crop", "true");
            in.putExtra("outputX", 100);
            in.putExtra("outputY", 100);
            in.putExtra("scale", true);
            in.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(in, 1);
        }
    });
```

Here is the onActivityMethod()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        mImageByteArray = data.getExtras().getByteArray(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_IMAGE);
        mImageUri = imageUri;
        mImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        mImageString = imageUri.toString();
        mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mImageByteArray, 0, mImageByteArray.length);
    }
}
```

I tried to get a byte array of the image, but i am getting a Null value in  the mImageByteArray variable (see the code above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the onClickListener on the "Add Image" button

There are no `crop` extras in Android, let alone for `ACTION_PICK`.

> Here is the onActivityMethod()

`ACTION_PICK` returns a `Uri`, as is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK). It does not return any extras.

Pass that `Uri` to your favorite image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso), so it can load that image on a background thread.

Or, fork your own background thread, and use that along with a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Pass that `InputStream` to `BitmapFactory` and its `decodeStream()` method. But, please, use an image-loading library.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am not allowed to use external libraries for this project.

Comment: @ShashankAC: Pretty much everything in Android involves "external libraries".

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to get the byte array:

```
public static byte[] convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024*8];
        int bytesRead =0;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1)
        {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Just get the file from the Uri and pass to this function.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you don't put the ByteArray in the Intent's extras, So you can't get it. Use [PutExtra(String name, byte[] value)](http://It%20seems%20that%20you%20don't%20put%20the%20ByteArray%20in%20the%20Intent's%20extras,%20So%20you%20can't%20get%20it.) to add your bytaArray to your Extra.

```
addImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,

android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            in.setType("image/*");
            in.putExtra("crop", "true");
            in.putExtra("outputX", 100);
            in.putExtra("outputY", 100);
            in.putExtra("scale", true);
            in.putExtra("return-data", true);
            in.putExtra("image_byte_array", myImageByteArray); //Add your byteArray to your Intent's extras
            startActivityForResult(in, 1);
        }
    });
```

Then you can retrieve it using [getByteArrayExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getByteArrayExtra(java.lang.String))

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        mImageByteArray = data.getByteArrayExtra("image_byte_array"); //Use same name as when you put it
        mImageUri = imageUri;
        mImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        mImageString = imageUri.toString();
        mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mImageByteArray, 0, mImageByteArray.length);
    }
}
```